App_Code in Visual Studio 2015 vs Visual Studio 2022
In VS 2015 website, I create datasets in the App_Code folder, added table adapters and link to stored procedure from SQL Server, which I can still do in VS2022.
In my code behind in VS 2015 (vb.net), I would use something like:
Dim returnCustomersDT as New customerDataset.sp_returnCustomersDataTable

In VS 2022, after I type Dim returnCustomersDT as New, intellisense doesn't show customerDataset.
I set the dataset to "Build Action: Compile", but that didn't fix the issue. The datasets are not 'seen' by VS 2022

App_Code is used by "Website" projects, not "Web Application" projects. I think VS2022 still supports "Websites" - but they are still effectively deprecated.

You haven't shared the structure of your project so this is a shot in the blind, but

I would try to a new class at the root of your project and look at
the namespace that is created for it.
Copy that namespace to your customerDataset class and see if intellisense picks it up

Note: I am aware that this might mess-up the references to that class from other parts of your code, but it would help you identify why the customerDataset isn't picked-up

Thank you Ted for you reply
I am testing VS 2022 on a new computer. This is a new website project. The 'customerDataset' is a Dataset (not a regular class) where I added a table adapter linked to a SQL server stored procedure. The file extension is XSD. I am more of a database guy and this is how i learned to retrieve data and show in a gridview in asp.net.
I created a new dataset at the root of the project and intellisense works. Not sure how to get the namespace.
Thank you again so much for your help.

When I launched the website, I got an error referring the existing dataset in App_Code folder. I deleted the file and now getting another error:"Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="FirstArticleInspection1.Global_asax" Language="vb" %>"
